# Vim: TABs of different widths in visual modes and insert mode?

Tags: vim, indentation

This thing works like the below but if `set tabstop=55`, it does not work: the TAB in insert mod and the TAB in visual-block mode are totally different TABs.

1. Visual Block Mode (or Visual mode)
2. Select part of the column and
3. then press >

I am indenting a large column file -- inserting TABs here-and-there and other trivial changes -- where I need to be able to see things correctly without having different TAB widths.

**How can I get TABs to be the same TAB with the same width over different modes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also set shiftwidth to be 55.

From the vim [help](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27shiftwidth%27)

```
                                                'shiftwidth' 'sw'
'shiftwidth' 'sw'       number  (default 8)
                        local to buffer
        Number of spaces to use for each step of (auto)indent.  Used for
        'cindent', >>, <<, etc.
```

So in your vimrc add

```
set shiftwidth=55
```

Comment: +1 should be the cause. also shiftwidth could be set to 0, so that ts value will be used by sw. and we could just change one option.

Comment: @Kent that does not look correct: `E487: Argument must be positive: shiftwidth=0`. It would be cool if only one modification and not both: 'set tabstop=55; set shiftwidth=55`.

Comment: @hhh here (vim 7.3) I can set sw=0. also if you read help info of sw, there is one sentence :`When zero the 'ts' value will be used. `

Comment: @Kent `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Aug 16 2012 15:12:57`, the same version but not working, neither `set sw=0` nor `set shiftwidth=0`. It must be positive value according to my Vim's error.

Comment: @hhh I think it was introduced in patch >600 (I'm having trouble finding the exact number). What patch is your vim up to.